# AppSync Schema Scalar Type for Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-ios

I am writing an iOS app which uses AppSync and DynamoDB as the BaaS. I need to pass an image (Binary) from the backend to the app via schema.graphql. However, based on this documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html

There's no scalar type in the schema for images (binary). Should I use String instead? Would the app client (iOS) be able to parse the String correctly as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Complex Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html#complex-objects) to manage images. This follows best practices where the image metadata is accessible over GraphQL and the actual blob is stored in a system that is amenable to large binary files.

AWS AppSync supports this pattern with the `S3Object` GraphQL type (here's [another example](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/#complex-objects) to follow for iOS).